# Wireshark HTTP requests

Tags: wireshark

I'm using Wireshark to sniff requests on my Android. I see that the Destination column is listing IP addresses. How can I get Wireshark to show the human-readable domain name before it's resolved to an IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select "resolve addresses" in the pre-sniffing options before starting the dump.

Answer (score 2):

You should open Edit - Preferences - Name Resolution

Enable network name resolution[√]

or right click on a IP -> [Manually Resolve Address]

I try this in Wireshark 1.8.3